# How to synchronise call in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

can you please tell me how to call synchronise method in jquery  or java script.
Actually problem is that I call one function on click button.And get some value .While getting   below function call and i am getting undefined value after some time i will get value.
I will explain with my example.
1)I need to get CASENAME value on click del button.I am getting the value from data base .While getting this deleteFolder function call .There i will get value undefined.
then after i will get real value here   alert("CASENAME"+CASENAME);I think i need to synchronise this method as we do in java.?

```
$(document).on('click', '.del', function(event) {

  ROW_ID = $(this).closest(".caseRowClick").attr("id");
  //getCaseNameValue();
  db.transaction(function (tx) {
            var caseName_h = $('.caseName_h').val();
            $yoursql = 'SELECT CaseName FROM CaseTable WHERE id ='+ ROW_ID;
            tx.executeSql($yoursql, [], function (tx, results) {
                CASENAME=results.rows.item(0).CaseName;
               alert("CASENAME"+CASENAME);
            });
});
  deleteData();
  deleteFolder();
  $(".ctrl").toggleClass("togg");
  event.stopPropagation();
});

function deleteFolder(){

     alert(CASENAME);
      window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs) {
        console.log("Root ================********************* " + fs.root.fullPath);

        TEXTFILE_PATH=fs.root.fullPath;
        fs.root.getDirectory(CASENAME, {create: true, exclusive: false},
          function(dirEntry) {
            dirEntry.removeRecursively(successfullyDelete, faildelete)
          });

      });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be passing that variable (*CASENAME*) around...

or the variable should be in the scope of both the functions.

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.del', function (event) {

    var ROW_ID = $(this).closest(".caseRowClick").attr("id");
    var CASENAME;
    //getCaseNameValue();
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        var caseName_h = $('.caseName_h').val();
        $yoursql = 'SELECT CaseName FROM CaseTable WHERE id =' + ROW_ID;
        tx.executeSql($yoursql, [], function (tx, results) {
            CASENAME = results.rows.item(0).CaseName;
            alert("CASENAME" + CASENAME);
        });
    });
    deleteData();
    deleteFolder(CASENAME);
    $(".ctrl").toggleClass("togg");
    event.stopPropagation();
});

function deleteFolder(CASENAME) {

    alert(CASENAME);
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {
        console.log("Root ================********************* " + fs.root.fullPath);

        TEXTFILE_PATH = fs.root.fullPath;
        fs.root.getDirectory(CASENAME, {
                create: true,
                exclusive: false
            },
            function (dirEntry) {
                dirEntry.removeRecursively(successfullyDelete, faildelete)
            });

    });

}
```

Comment: Not getting ..Getting undefined ..:(

Comment: I thing the value is really `undefined` for `results.rows.item(0).CaseNam`

Comment: No after few second it pop up this alert  alert("CASENAME" + CASENAME);it is getting fine

Comment: problem is that this alert fire alert(CASENAME); first then  alert("CASENAME" + CASENAME);