# Need some concept of threading in java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some concept of threading java script.Actually  I struck in one problem .Problem is that 
I have one  function A () calling function B and C.

```
function A(){
   B();
   C();
}

function B(){
   //doing some task 
   i=something;
   alert(i);
}

function C(){
   // i need value I here.
   alert(i)    //getting undefined 
}
```

I need to synchronised call ...

Comment: Define `i` as a global variable.

Comment: All those calls are synchronized. In other words, the call to `B()` will be called and completed, before the call to `C()`.  So I'm not sure why you're talking about [Threading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)), when it looks like you're talking about [Scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)).

Comment: please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689556/how-to-synchronise-call-in-jquery-or-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
function A(){
   C(B());
}

function B(){
   //doing some task 
   var i=something;
   return i;
}

function C(i){
   // i need value I here.
   alert(i)    
}
```

or split out for readability

```
function A(){
   var resultFromB = B(); //
   C(resultFromB);
}

function B(){
   //doing some task 
   var result=something;
   return result; // return it to calling function
}

function C(resultOriginallyFromB) { // passing it
   alert(resultOriginallyFromB);    
}
```

Comment: **+1** for avoiding globals.

Comment: not quite clear that `B()` is returning something to be passed along later, but it does save on memory by not re-declaring a variable.

Comment: @Brombomb you mean I should have `var returnedFromB=B();` in C?

Comment: @mplungjan I think it would help with readability, and be a simpler form of code. This may help the author fully grasp what you are doing so it can be applied later and not fall into some kind of nesting hell.

Answer (score 1):

Set `i` as global like,

```
var i=null;// global i
function A(){
   B();
   C();
}

function B(){
   //doing some task 
   i=something;
   alert(i);
}

function C(){
   i need value I here.
   alert(i)    //getting undefined 
}
```

Read [this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function)

**Alternatively,** you can use `return` in `B()` like,

```
function A(){
   i=B();
   C(i);//passing i in C()
}

function B(){
   //doing some task 
   i=something;
   alert(i);
   return i;//return i
}

function C(i){
   // value i has been passed in.
   alert(i);
}
```

Comment: I'll give you the benefit of the doubt

Comment: Ok, I also removed the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it should not really be alerting `undefined` in function  C. As `i` would have become globally defined already, without the use of `var`.

Besides try doing it this way, so that you don't clutter the global space:

```
(function() {

  var i;

  function A(){
   B();
   C();
  }

  function B(){
     //doing some task 
     i=4;       // --- or something
     alert(i);  // --- will alert 4
  }

  function C(){
     // i need value I here.
     alert(i)    // --- will alert 4
  }

  A();  // --- Assuming you were calling 'A' earlier as well

})();
```

And yes, nothing related to *threading* here.

Comment: what about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689556/how-to-synchronise-call-in-jquery-or-javascript

Comment: Have a look there, now.

Comment: please check again this question .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689556/how-to-synchronise-call-in-jquery-or-javascript